# How to yank a word with its surrounded quotes?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Is there an easy vim keyboard shortcut to yank a word, including its surrounding quotes?
For instance I would like to yank `'my_word'` from the statement below:

```
tmp = my_func(arg1, 'my_word')
```

How can I do that? I have surround plugin installed.

`yi'` only yanks `my_word`, but not `'my_word'`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you aware of `:help text-objects`? It seems like you want `ya'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the keybindings you wanted..

- **va'** selects the word(s) inside the quote
- **va)** selects the word(s) inside brackets
- **va}** selects the word(s) inside curly braces

And then press **y** to yank.

Bonus : replace **v** with **d** to delete accordingly.